# Solution for rendering React app from legacy JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, redux

For example I have ReactApp which is packed via `Webpack`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

let store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    {},
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
)

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
            TEST IF WORKS
        </div>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root-element')
)
```

And I would like to call it from legacy JS function, which is available in global scope, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawReactApp(el, initialData) {
    // Render ReactApp on dynamic HTML element ID
}
</script>
```

The problem is that:

1) I need to render multiple ReactApp's using `drawReactApp()` (render widgets).

2) I can't find solution for rendering ReactApp using legacy JS code, because I can't include React JS scripts, only bundle file (this is limitation).

3) I can render ReactApp on "hardcoded" HTML ID element (for example: "#root-element"), but can't make ID dynamic (only legacy JS can know on which element ReactApp should be rendered)

Is there any advice or solutions on this?

Thank you!

Comment: So are you asking how to dynamically create an element on the page? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, you understand clearly. Render an ReactApp on dynamically created HTML element from legacy JS, using only ReactApp bundle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your «ReactApp», you could create a global function to render it:

```js
window.drawThisReactApp = (into, initialData) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider ...><ReactApp {...initialData} /></Provider>, into);
}
```

Then, in "legacy" JS:

```html
<script>
  window.drawThisReactApp(document.getElementById(...), {...});
</script>
```

*N.B. No reference to `React` or `ReactDOM` needed here.*

Comment: Right, but then I need to include in global HTML React.js files. Is there any solution for render ReactApp using only ReactApp bundle file?

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to include React globally.

Comment: Ok, how to do that? I ask, because ReactDOM is not available in global scope, when I include ReactApp.js bundled file.

Comment: `ReactDOM` is an `import` within your ReactApp

Comment: My fault. Yes, that's the solution. Thank you!